# Poisson Covariance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to understand the following without using any special formulas but only by independence of increments and linearity of covariance.

Let $N(\star)$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda=a$ and let $m<r<s<t$:
$$Cov[N(t)-N(r),N(s)-N(m)]$$

By independence of increments, I have 
$$Cov[N(t)-N(s),N(s)-N(m)]+Cov[N(s)-N(r),N(s)-N(m)]$$

I think $Cov[N(t)-N(s),N(s)-N(m)]=0$ but I don't know what to do with the other term. Recommendations on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
 & \mathsf{Cov}[N(t) - N(r) , N(s)-N(m)] 
\\[1ex]
 =~& \mathsf{Cov}[\big(N(t)-N(s)\big)+\big(N(s)-N(r)\big),N(s)-N(m)]
\\[1ex]
 =~& \mathsf{Cov}[N(t)-N(s),N(s)-N(m)]+\mathsf{Cov}[N(s)-N(r),N(s)-N(m)]
\\[1ex]
 =~& 0+\mathsf{Cov}[N(s)-N(r),N(s)-N(r)]+\mathsf{Cov}[N(s)-N(r),N(r)-N(m)]
\\[1ex]
 =~& 0+\mathsf{Cov}[N(s)-N(r),N(s)-N(r)]+0 
\\[1ex]
 =~& \mathsf{Var}[N(s)-N(r)]
\end{align}
which is $\lambda(s-r)$ or $a(s-r)$ though that uses the variance of a Poisson distribution

Comment: Would look better with begin{align} and end{align}?

Comment: @BrianTung feel free to change it, but since I cannot get the three covariances on the same line, I am not inclined to do much about it.  The point is that only the overlap matters, and that is then a variance

Comment: I've made an attempt.  If you don't like the way it looks, you can either revert yourself, or leave a comment, and I will gladly revert (and delete these comments).

Comment: @BrianTung I don't feel strongly one way or another, but if you think it is better then thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Bilinearity of Covariance, and the fact that the Poisson random variables in disjoint intervals will be independent.

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
\mathsf{Cov}(N_t-N_r, N_s-N_m) ~=~&\mathsf{Cov}((N_t-N_s)+(N_s-N_r), (N_s-N_r)+(N_r-N_m)) \\[1ex]=~& {\cancelto0{\mathsf{Cov}(N_t-N_s,N_s-N_r)}+\cancelto0{\mathsf{Cov}(N_t-N_s,N_r-N_m)}\\+\mathsf{Cov}(N_s-N_r,N_s-N_r)+\cancelto0{\mathsf{Cov}(N_s-N_r,N_r-N_m)}}
\\[1ex] =~& \mathsf{Var}(N_s-N_r)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Beaten to the punch